# Vue: setting up computed properties so that BOM is available

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering

What Im trying to achieve: 
I want to create a computed property that depends on the BOM screen (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_screen.asp). 
somthing like:

```
  computed:{
      screenWidth:function(){
          return screen.availWidth;
      }
  }
```

This means I can adjust my template based on this propery thus making it responsive. In my real project I would return a whole object which is used in other computed properties.

Problem: 
The screen object is not available for computed properties in an ssr context (express-vue). (it is for methods though). I guess that this is caused by the time computed properties are executed for the first time, which I think happened to be before the Browser BOM is available.

What would solve my problem:
If there is a option that makes a computed property executed for the first time when the Browser BOM is available. I guess after the file is mounted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research I found out that:

1. screen is only availible after the mount hook as Stephan-v suggested
2. screen is not changing unless you change the Browser Configuration
3. To make my template respond to the availible screen I need to write an Eventlistener that listens to the 'resize' event of window which can look like this:

   ```
    mounted() {
       window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize);
    },
    beforeDestroy: function () {
       window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resize);
    },
   ```

in the method this.resize you will have full access to the BOM.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform your logic in the `mounted` or `beforeMount` lifecycles because that is the only way to ensure you are actually in a browser environment.

At that point you could simply set a data property to the required `window` object and read it from there. I am not sure how this would be implemented with a computed property. But the question is; do you really need this to be a cached property to begin with?

Comment: So yes I can get the initial screen values via mount. But now I want it reactive so I need to use a computed property or a watcher. Cant use the computed so I tried the watcher. The problem is that the only time set the screenValues is in the mounted hook. Now I want check it changed but the dependency wouldnt update if the screen updates. Basically the dependency only changes via a methods, computed, lifecycle hooks, events binded by vue or watched but not if the BOM changes. So I cant watch what I dont set but I cant set because I need to know if it changed.